# Applications of cut-elimination

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-theory

I'm doing a project relating a logic topic. I chose cut-elimination and, although the topic seems quite interesting, my proffessor is asking us for applications, hopefully on other areas non related to logic. However I don't seem to find any articles relating this topic.

Could anybody provide me any reference to an application of cut-elimination?

Comment: @QuantumFool I've googled severas times, finding only applications in logic, I'm looking something like applications in computer science.

Answer (score 2):

The Prolog programming language depends on Gentzen's theorem in some ways.

Comment: Thank you. I found a reference which unfortunately I can't access from my university. Is there a classic article on this work?

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question that..as someone who is trying to find an excuse to make a living out of studying formal logic...I should be asking myself.

Ever looked at linear logic?...And the cut elimination associated with that?...which SURPRISINGLY follows the Cut-Elimination Theorem?

But here's another surprise: It generalizes your standard classical/intuitionistic treatment of Gentzen Calculus, into a more general propositional language, that gets ugly in terms of its properties and semantics but it's actually getting a bit of hype from the computer science community as a good way to formalize programs mathematically. [Here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/030439759390181R/1-s2.0-030439759390181R-main.pdf?_tid=e827b36a-9a7c-11e6-b9bb-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1477377374_5c605526c8b6242d2c459453090ef0ab) is a (quite dense) paper on this sort of thing for some inspiration.

Not sure how "non-related to logic" he wants the application to be, as computer science is a very logic-oriented discipline. But at least it's application to *something* outside the confinements of its own branch of mathematics.